# Python prints my class object memory address instead of values of my array

Tags: python, oop

I want to print each element registered in my "student_list" array. But Python prints the memory location of each of my values. I am totally new to OOP using python. Any help or comments are highly appreciated.

```
class Student():

    def __init__(self, name, grade_level, subject, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.grade_level = grade_level
        self.subject = subject
        self.grade = grade

    @classmethod
    def student_input(cls):
        return cls(
            input("Name: "),
            input("Garde Level: "),
            input("Subject: "),
            int(input("Grade: ")),
        )

    def student_info(self):
        print("************************")
        print("Name: " + self.name+"\n"+"Grade Level: "+self.grade_level +
              "\n"+"Subject: "+self.subject + "\n"+"Grade: "+str(self.grade))
        print("************************")


student_list = []
print("**********************")
user1 = Student.student_input()
student_list.append(user1)
print("**********************")
user2 = Student.student_input()
student_list.append(user2)
print("**********************")

print(user1.student_info)

for student in student_list:
    print(student)
```

### Output:

```
PS C:\Users\D3L10\Documents\PythonML\iPythonProj> python .\schoolSystem.py
**********************
Name: Andy
Garde Level: Freshman
Subject: Physics
Grade: 92
**********************
Name: James
Garde Level: Sophmore
Subject: Algebra
Grade: 82
**********************
<bound method Student.student_info of <__main__.Student object at 0x00580610>>
<__main__.Student object at 0x00580610>
<__main__.Student object at 0x00819DB0>
```

Comment: Remember the syntax of function call.

Comment: `print(user1.student_info())`

Comment: Op should have found it. The whole point of the exercise is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your method student_info by the dunder method **str** as follow.

```
def __str__(self):
    return   f"""
    ************************\n
    Name: {self.name}\n
    Grade Level: {self.grade_level}\n
    Subject: {self.subject} \n
    Grade: {self.grade}\n       
    ************************"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Method call should be performed with `()`
Code:

```
class Student():

    def __init__(self, name, grade_level, subject, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.grade_level = grade_level
        self.subject = subject
        self.grade = grade

    @classmethod
    def student_input(cls):
        return cls(
            input("Name: "),
            input("Garde Level: "),
            input("Subject: "),
            int(input("Grade: ")),
        )

    def student_info(self):
        print("************************")
        print("Name: " + self.name+"\n"+"Grade Level: "+self.grade_level +
              "\n"+"Subject: "+self.subject + "\n"+"Grade: "+str(self.grade))
        print("************************")


student_list = []
print("**********************")
user1 = Student.student_input()
student_list.append(user1)
print("**********************")
user2 = Student.student_input()
student_list.append(user2)
print("**********************")

print(user1.student_info) # where you failed, not compliying with method call syntax in python
print(user1.student_info()) # correct way to obtain your print.
```

Output:

```
**********************
Name: >? Foo
Garde Level: >? 7
Subject: >? Bart
Grade: >? 8
**********************
Name: >? Fooz
Garde Level: >? 9
Subject: >? pijzef
Grade: >? 3
**********************
<bound method Student.student_info of <__main__.Student object at 0x0000012BF97138C8>>
************************
Name: Foo
Grade Level: 7
Subject: Bart
Grade: 8
************************
None
```

---

Otherwise, as stated in other answers, provide a **srt** method and only print the object. Python will infer a `objet.__str__()` call.
This is more "OOP-ic"

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your class a `__str__` or `__repr__` method or it won't know how to present itself as a string. If you simply rename your existing `student_info` method to one of these it will work just by doing `print(user1)`

Also, the reason `print(user1.student_info)` didn't do what you expected is because you are asking it to print the method itself not the result of the method. It should be `print(user1.student_info())`